# Unordered List Issue with JavaScript, HTML, CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, unordered

I'm doing a course and I can't get the HTML and JavaScript part correct of unordered lists. This part of the course is to create an unordered list with HTML, CSS, and Javascript.  What's missing or needs to be added?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <head>
    <title>My CSS experiment</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <u>
      <li>Hello World!</li>
      <li>This is my first CSS example</li>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <h3>List of items</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>first item</li>
    <li>second item</li>
    <li>third item</li>
  </ul>

  <ul>  {float: left; list-style-type:none;}
  <ul> li {float: left; margin-right:20px;}
  <ul> li span {display:block}

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this your actual code? .... You need to learn the basic , you can't have two doctypes, two html tags .... unclosed tags like the first ul and that code on `{}` brackets is style you need the proper format....

Comment: You should only have one head tag in a document not two.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering because I think it'd be more helpful to your learning (and anyone else following whatever course you're in right now) to post some corrective information and tell you what you're doing wrong. This is the spirit of stack overflow.

You've got a couple duplicate tags.

For the most part, try to stick to 1 of each in the following:

- `DOCTYPE` (has no closing `</DOCTYPE>` tag)
- `<html>` Tag
- `<head>` Tag
- `<body>` Tag

with the exception of the DOCTYPE, you should have closing tags for each of these.

**You can click on the below link to see your (corrected) code in action!**

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VjaXwd?editors=1000

Now, with that being said, you certainly have a long way to go. Welcome to the world of code!

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <body>
        <h4>An Unordered List:</h4>
        <ul>
            <li>Coffee</li>
            <li>Tea</li>
            <li>Milk</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```